# combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When using queryset in Django date range getting error

```
from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
to_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
min_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.time.min)
max_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(to_date, datetime.time.max)
daily_en = All_enquiries.objects.filter(enquired_at__range = (min_dt, max_dt))
```

when using variable manually value its working fine below

```
from_date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 9)
to_date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 9)
```

Comment: This is because of the data from the `request.POST` are ***string*** type. You need to convert it to `datetime` object

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you cast the string returned from request.POST.get() to datetime.date it should work, but I don't know the content of the request.POST.get()

Comment: Use some of this examples: https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/ depending on the date format of the string

Comment: Am getting input type=date format please comment how to covert to datetime

Comment: add this lines of code:
print(from_date)
print(to_date)
to see which format return the POST request, without this info I don't know how to convert it